# How to use AD groups to assign O365 mailbox sizes

Tags: powershell, active-directory, office365

Is there a way to do the above? I've managed to follow the below link successfully but we're looking to set different limits based on the user's role.

[The aforementioned link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2490230/how-to-set-exchange-online-mailbox-sizes-and-limits-in-the-office-365)

Where is says :
Additional filters can be applied to the Get-Mailbox cmdlet or to the Get-User cmdlet to control the users for whom the change is applied. The following is an example in which three cmdlets are used to filter the command to the sales department of an organization:

```
Get-User | where {$_.Department -eq "Sales"} | Get-Mailbox | Set-Mailbox -ProhibitSendQuota < Value > -ProhibitSendReceiveQuota < Value > -IssueWarningQuota < Value >
```

Kinda got me confused as to where it's pulling the "Sales" group from?

Probably being a muppet here but any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, using the Active Directory PowerShell module:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Department | Where-Object { $_.Department -eq "Sales" } | [...]
```

But that's just pulling everybody and looking at the Department field from Active Directory.  That's the example the article gives, but it doesn't answer your question about assigning quotas based on groups.

I suspect what you'll want based on your problem is this:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName | Get-ADUser | Get-MailBox | Set-ProhibitSendQuota [...]
```

I don't know if you need `Get-ADUser` there or if the output of `Get-ADGroupMember` can be piped directly to `Get-MailBox`.  I no longer administer Exchange, so I don't have access to those cmdlets anymore.  `$GroupName` can be the group's name, distinguished name, or even the SID, IIRC.

Comment: `Get-User` is a Microsoft cmdlet, so you could retract the accusation of lack of testing code; It's available when you connect to a remote session for Exchange Online, or Exchange Server 2016. See [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996896(v=exchg.160).aspx). Additionally, Department is a property on the return object of Get-User (at least when the RecipientType is of 'UserMailbox').

Comment: @Robin Eh, fair enough.  Like I said, I haven't administered Exchange a long time.  To give you an idea, the last time I did it we were still using `Get-QADUser`.

Comment: @BaconBits Afraid it won't let me pipe to it :/ "The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not input or the input and it's properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

+ CatergoryInfo         : InvalidArgument: (CN=Firstname Lastname,........DC=Local:PSObject) [Get-Mailbox], ParameterBindingExeception
+FullyQuallifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound, Get-Mailbox"

Comment: @DavidGolding How about `Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName | Get-Mailbox | Set-ProhibitSendQuota [...]` or `Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName | ForEach-Object { Get-Mailbox -Identity $_.DistinguishedName | Set-ProhibitSendQuota [...] }`

Comment: Hi @BaconBits still not working, is there a way to get Powershell to read from a text file. I can just populate it with 1stname.lastname?

Comment: @DavidGolding Lots of ways.  `Get-Content` or `Import-Csv` will work.

Comment: @BaconBits would Get-Content be used instead of Get-User as I tried it with both but no joy (before asking you)

Comment: @DavidGolding I don't know what that question means. Get-User returns user accounts from Exchange's global catalog.  Get-Content reads data from a file.  Other than the same verb, they're not related.

Comment: Sorry ignore my last @BaconBits I had the Get-Content & Get-User wrong way round, been too long since I used coding to solve issues not thinking properly. You solved my issue so if you'd like to put it as an answer I will change the question. :)